# Python append several data frames into one inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm scrapping info about coins. I need to append all scrapped data to one Dataframe.

I have following code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

def scraping_func(coin_id):
    """  
    This function recives "coins_id" from "coins_to_scrape list".
    It scrapes all data that I need and puts it to "df" Dataframe
    Then it saves this Dataframe to excel file (%coin_id%.xlsx)
    The last lines of the function are:  (I cut my code because it's big) 
    """   
    df = df[['Country', 'Value', 'Year', 'Metal', 'Marks', 'Mintage', 'Krause', 'Price', 'Quality', 'Details', 'Avers', 'Revers', 'Gcoins_link']]
    excel_name = '{}.xlsx'.format(coin_id)                               
    df.to_excel(excel_name)      
    for i in dfs:
        dfs = df.append(dfs, ignore_index=True)
        dfs.to_excel('adfasdf.xlsx')

coins_to_scrape = [514, 515, 179080, 45518, 521, 111429]        # The list of ID that I need to scrape
for i in coins_to_scrape:                                       # For each coin in the list
    scraping_func(i)                                            # call the "scraping_func" function
```

It works great. But this code creates separate excel document for each coins that I'm passing to the function. But there are thousands coins to scrape so I'd like to append each Dataframes to the one and then save it to the excel file.

I tried to find a solution on the internet but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of dataframes and then concatenate them into a single dataframe:

```
def scraping_func(coin_id):
    # do stuff to create dataframe
    return df[['Country', 'Value', ..., 'Revers', 'Gcoins_link']]

coins_to_scrape = [514, 515, 179080, 45518, 521, 111429]

# construct list of dataframes via list comprehension
df_list = [scraping_func(i) for i in coins_to_scrape]

# combine dataframes in list
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi, jpp. Thank you so much. It works perfect to me. Cheers :)